# Saving to the database via jQuery and .ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following script is failing and I have no idea why. Can anyone see anything glaring? I just used and alert to make sure that the userID and the postID were correct and they were so I know the call to the values is correct and I have the processing page in the same directory just to get it to work for now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#saveme').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_recipe.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'postID': $('#post_id').val(), 'userID': $('#user_id').val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("This recipe has been saved in your profile area!");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            },
            //alert('PostID: '+ $('#post_id').val() +' UserID: '+$('#user_id').val());  
        });

    });
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? do you get any error messages? Is the data transfered correctly to the php script? Does the php script save it correctly into mysql (or whereever)?

Comment: The code you posted looks unalarming. You could possible have a problem with your server side code.

Comment: you may need to be more specific about what the script is doing, what does it return (network tab in dev tools) maybe post the php code, etc.

Comment: Do you have any response alerted in error handler? Maybe there is an exception in php or something?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Nothing happens. It just doesn't do anything.

here is the PHP on the processing page:

<?php 

/*Typical database connection variables here*/
 
// database connection
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
  
// new data
 $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
 $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
 
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_saved_recipes (user_id,post_id,date_added) VALUES (:user_id,:post_id,:today)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id,
                   ':post_id'=> $post_id,
       ':today' => date('Y-m-d')));